# How to get a shell condition is true or false in rust

Tags: shell, rust

I found [std::process](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) in document. But it seems that it cannot work. For example:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::process::Command;

    let command = Command::new("command")
        .arg("-sq")
        .arg("ls")
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    println!("{command:#?}");
}
```

Output:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', 1.rs:8:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

But run the command in shell:

```bash
$ command -sq ls && echo true || echo false
true
```

So how can I get a output like shell in rust?

Comment: `command` is a shell builtin, but `std::process` doesn't use the shell.

Comment: Umm, so are there any way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Achieve what effect? What does `command -sq ls` do? Apparently your shell is different than mine. I could answer how to do the print true/false part, but it wouldn't help solve the error you're seeing.

Comment: `command -sq ls` means find ls's executable file , but be quite (without output). And I'm using fish shell.

Comment: I'm guessing this is simply to detect if the program exists? Does this answer your question [Finding executable in PATH with Rust](/q/37498864/2189130) Or if you're going to run it anyway, perhaps this will help [Check if a command is in PATH/executable as process](/q/35045996/2189130)

Comment: @XXiaoA you can just run the shell itself as executable, with the builtin as your script.

Comment: @kmdreko interestingly `command` checks if a command will work in the shell, it will "hit" on shell builtins and aliases, not just on binaries on the path.

Comment: @Masklinn actually, I not only want to check if the command exists. I hope my script runs after user's shell condition is true.

Comment: Is `command` a reference to the standard, built-in shell command named `command`, or is it a badly named stand-in for some other command you have but we don't? (Also, **which shell**? On POSIXy ones, `command` doesn't take `-s` or `-q`)

Comment: @XXiaoA, ahh. This really needs to be asked about fish. If you want to use a shell builtin, that's a core part of the question -- include it in title and tagging. (This isn't a Rust problem; to reproduce it in Python, for example, run `import subprocess; subprocess.run(['command', '-sq', 'ls'])` and you'll see a Python version of the same issue).

Answer (score 1):

The most direct equivalent would be this:

```
let command = Command::new("fish")
    .args(["-c", "command -sq ls"])
    .output()
    .unwrap();

if command.status.success() {
    println!("true");
} else {
    println!("false");
}
```

This creates a `fish` shell which then executes your `command` command. The `.success()` method can be used to infer if the command succeeded or failed same as `&&` and `||` in your script.

Comment: Is there a fish equivalent to bash's `bash -c '"$@"'`? If so, you could get access to builtins while still being able to pass an exact argv array.

Comment: Fish. Can use `fish -C "command -sq ls". What's more thanks for your help!